# FQL photo and photo_src table src using http but no https

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, facebook-fql, photo

I am using the photo and photo_src table to retrieve the src of photos on my Facebook page but there doesn't seem an option to get an https src. When serving my app over https the browser throws a warning that their is insecure content (the photos retrieved have an http protocol). I have tried modifiying the src retrieved and programatically replacing the http with https but the browser won't load the photos because their is no security certificate from the website hosting the Facebook image e.g.
http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/579891_432647290089868_873356675_s.jpg

Surely this is a common problem, I have tried searching for this but no luck. Please help, thanks.

Comment: How are you executing your FQL queries?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try the Graph API and pass the **`return_ssl_resources=1`** parameter as explained here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures.

For the record: I just tried the FQL example for the photo_src table that is in the docs and I get the https urls by default:

```
SELECT src, width, height FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id = 10150931418786729 AND width > 480
```

with these results

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/457873_10150931418786729_1769228986_o.jpg",
      "width": 2048,
      "height": 2048
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/417314_10150931418786729_1769228986_n.jpg",
      "width": 960,
      "height": 960
    },
    {
      "src": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/417314_10150931418786729_1769228986_n.jpg",
      "width": 720,
      "height": 720
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Confirmed. I get https paths to images using an FQL query and the PHP SDK.

Comment: Boom! Wish I had found this earlier. Confirmed, legend.

Answer (score 2):

You get the https URL by default because the user you are querying has the "Secure Browsing" enabled into his account options.

Try to get the pictures from an user with this option disabled. You'll see the http:// URL, not the https://.

No way to force https even for users that haven't the secure browsing option enabled??